# Problem after trying to install 64bit Ubuntu using Wubi from mounted iso file

Tags: installation, wubi

I tried installing Ubuntu x64. I mounted the .iso file using daemon tools, and copied its contents on my USB. I already configured BIOS to boot from USB.

I found *wubi.exe* in that mounted `.iso` file. I ran it and it installed Ubuntu, then it said, I must reboot. I selected *reboot now* options. When it boots, it says `no wubildr`, then it says *completing the ubuntu installation* (or something like that) and some stuff. if I press <kbd>ESC</kbd> It goes to black screen, and nothing happens.

I have :
HP pavilion G7 1303
CPU: 64 bit CPU
GRAPHIC CARD: AMD Radeon HD 7450M, 1 GB Memory

Comment: Can you still boot to Windows OS. Then follow this [Wubi Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WubiGuide/)

Comment: If you were to install Ubuntu to a partition on your HDD, you will not use the WUBI installer but the Ubuntu ISO installer which is to be burned on a CD or install on a USB. It is not enough that you copy contents of the .iso file to a USB.

You may have to clarify your question in order for people to help you. Do you want to install Ubuntu inside Windows (WUBI)? Or you want to install it in another partition (dual boot)?

Comment: Check this guide on how to run Ubuntu installer from the USB. http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows

Comment: To fix no wubildr, just copy wubildr to the root of your first partition.

Comment: @mitch But... where is that partition?

Comment: It's not required to copy wubildr. That message doesn't indicate there's a problem and it's finding wubildr on the next partition (otherwise the install wouldn't start). The first problem is the creation of the USB was incorrect, and installing wubi was not intended. The second problem is probably a graphics card incompatibility.

Comment: @bcbc About that second problem... Is my graphics card too good for it or what? It isn't that bad. or it is just not compatible? 

And how do I make ubuntu work?

Comment: @MatejKranjec your symptoms are very common - especially with radeon or nvidia cards. So you should boot with `nomodeset`: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132 (post #8) has some Wubi-specific instructions (method 1 for you).

Comment: @bcbc Now that he installed using Wubi, and he\s getting "When it boots, it says no wubildr", maybe copying the file would help.    Matej Kranjec If everything is installed using defaults, that would be your C: partition.

Comment: @Mitch no that's just a diagnostic output from wubildr.mbr: /dev/sda1 is probably the boot partition and the C:\ partition where the /wubildr is located is on /dev/sda2 or 3. So you see that message on all partitions with no wubildr until it finds it. Copying it will just get rid of the message but not solve the real issue.

Comment: @bcbc I tried that and it WORKED!!! But when it boots there is a windows called "installation" (or something, I have it in Slovenian. Then it says "root filesystem is not set" and something.
How can I fix that and can I fix it without reformatting?

Comment: @MatejKranjec On Wubi that's caused by errors from `parted` used by the ubuntu installer. Probably minor partition table issue, or leftover GPT. Best to drop to a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and run `sudo fdisk -l` and `sudo parted -l` - see if they output any errors. `sudo reboot` restarts the computer.

Answer (score 1):

There is problem with Grub loader and you have overwritten Grub on windows boot loader 
first you have to fix mbr in windows.

You can do this with the windows installation disk. After booting Disk choose repair option

Select Cmd then type the following commands

```
bootrec/fixmbr
bootrec/fixboot
```

Then Reboot

This will remove grub loader and let you run windows.

First delete ubuntu partitiion you created.

For dual boot system first create partition  using disk management utility. You can find it by right click on my computer > manage> disk management from left panel.

**Make bootable media of Ubuntu**

In Ubuntu installation you have to install root system in the blank partition you created, once done you then reboot

You will now have the options for choosing system (Ubuntu or Windows)